# Redirecting /category/postname to /year/month

Tags: apache, .htaccess, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll to power my blog and I'd like to change my url structure from `/category/postname` to `/year/month/postname`. I need to redirect links to the old structure to the new structure. I know, this might be difficult without a database to query.

I know how to configure Jekyll to output this structure. The problem is redirecting old links to the new one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jekyll...but you can try fetching your pages based on their file creation date ...I'm guessing it stores pages as static files. So in .htaccess redirect your requests to a script that gets the file created on /year/month/postname and outputs it to the browser.

Comment: Or you can hack Jekyll to save your files in that format /year/month/postname.

Comment: I literally just ran into this same issue when I removed /writing from my permalink structure last week. :-/

Comment: @lansen GitHub Pages doesn't support .htaccess (it's not apache).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Jekyll Post Alias Generator](https://github.com/tsmango/jekyll_alias_generator)?

Comment: I know how to change the structure. I need to redirect links to the old structure, to the new one.

Comment: redirects are not handled at all by Jekyll, you will need to either add them to your nginx config, or if using apache, to you .htaccess file

Comment: I just re-answered... is this a bit more on target?

Comment: You could edit all your old posts, adding the new structure as an alias in the YAML metadata, and then set the new structure as default on any new posts.

Comment: Yea, that seems to be my only option. Thanks :)